# Difficult sum $\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\sqrt{k}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can anyone help me with this sum I have tried separating in even and odd temps but couldn't achieve anything

Comment: what makes you think a closed form is available?

Comment: There is a [closed form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B%28-1%29%5Ek+k%5Ea%2C%7Bk%2C1%2Cn%7D%5D) with the incomplete zeta function

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this sum?

Comment: @TymaGaidash the incomplete zeta function is just a symbol for a sum which generally does not have a closed form.  In effect you may get something (unchecked) perhaps like $\sum\limits _{k=1}^n(-1)^k\sqrt{k} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \sqrt{k} -\sqrt{8}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \sqrt{k}$ which you then hide with symbols

Comment: @RobertIsrael I am trying to find the limit of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{1\leq k\leq n}(-1)^k\sqrt{k}$

Comment: for even $n$ you could pair up the terms:
$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \sqrt{k} = (\sqrt{2}-1) + (\sqrt{4} - \sqrt{3}) + ... = \sum_{k=1}^{n/2} \sqrt{2 k}-\sqrt{2 k-1}$ and see if this gets you anywhere. The closed form will probably still include something like a Hurwitz zeta function though.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{2k} - \sqrt{2k-1} = 2^{-3/2} k^{-1/2} + O(k^{-3/2})$, and relate $\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-1/2}$ to a Riemann sum.  No Hurwitz zeta functions needed.  But odd and even $n$ will give you different limits.